# How to open and view the folder from my computer?

Tags: java, file, directory

Edited Question:

```
try{
    folder=jTextField1.getText()+"_portfolio";


        String path="E:/test folder/"+folder+"";
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(path);
    }catch(Exception E){

    }
```

I got error method open in class java.awt.Desktop cannot be applied to given types.

Comment: try flipping the '/' for '\' - the windows stuff may not understand.

Comment: Try having a look at [`Desktop#browse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)

Comment: You can also try `Process p = new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe", "/select," + file.getAbsolutePath()).start()`

Comment: In regard to 'given types'  The documentation I linked to explicitly states the method takes a `File` not a `String`!  As an aside, you seem to be 'coding by magic'.  That won't work.  You need to read the documentation, and try to understand what it is telling you.

Comment: On a side note `}catch(Exception E){

    }`.  Don't ignore exception output!  Change that to `}catch(Exception E){
E.printStackTrace();
    }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29).  E.G.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(theDirectory);
```

#### SSCCE

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;

public class BrowseDirectory {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String userHomePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File userHome = new File(userHomePath);
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(userHome);
    }
}
```

#### Update

Although the directory appears as "My Videos"  to the end user, forming a file inside the directory and checking the properties of the file, reveals the underlying name is "Videos".

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;

public class BrowseDirectory {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String userHomePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File userHome = new File(userHomePath);
        // uses the corect path separator for the OS
        File videos = new File(userHome, "Videos");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(videos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
            String path = "C:\\path\\of\\your\\folder\\";
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            runtime.exec("explorer.exe "+path);
            System.out.println("open");
        } catch (Exception E) {
        }
```

you can use any path that you want but convert it 1st to string and please be aware in java "\" should written "\\"

hope it works :)

Comment: No.. I tried this code. But I have open my documents folder only.. i want to open E:\\ folder..